# how to get scala higher-kinded type to work

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

I'm trying to improve my understanding of higher-kinded type in Scala. While I went back to the basic, i got stuck on the following:

```
 def fooList[A <: Int](x: List[A]): List[A] = x.map{ e => e + 1 }
```

The Scala compiler does not accept it which, i do not understand. "A" must be a subclass of Int. hence whatever type under Int that shall be passed there should work. Why does it complain? Can someone advise me here ?

M

Comment: What does this have to do with higher-kinded types?

Answer (score 3):

`A` really must be an `Int` in this case, because you can't create a sub-class of `Int`, but the compiler doesn't seem to want to prove that. That aside, since `A <: Int`, the `+` method of `Int` returns an `Int`.

So `e + 1` is an `Int` and not an `A` (even if `A` must be an `Int`, anyway). Therefore, `x.map(e => e + 1)` returns a `List[Int]` and not a `List[A]`. In order to return `List[A]`, you need some class `A` with a `+` method that also returns `A`, which you don't.

Comment: hummm if i understood you well, Did i just confuse compile time type enforcement with runtime type enforcement ? still sounds weird.

Comment: There isn't runtime type enforcement other than thrown exceptions from bad casts, but that doesn't apply here. Simply put, if `A` is a subclass of `Int`, an `A` plus an `Int` is an `Int`, and not an `A` -- simply because of the type signature of `+` on `Int`.

Comment: Yes, i just meant i think i understand you. My confusion comes from the fact that i was thinking polymorphism while we are at compile time here and that does not work. If you have a class A and B with A > B, a method that return an A in signature can return a B instance.

Comment: To be pedantic, it's not true that `A` must be `Int`. Just because you can't make a subclass of `Int` doesn't mean you can't come up with a _subtype_ of `Int`. For example, having definition `val a: Int = 42` you could have singleton type `a.type` which is a subtype of `Int`.